# How do I fix this CMake race condition?

Tags: cmake

During the install step, I have these two rules:

```
install(
    FILES foo-extra.cmake
    DESTINATION cmake
        COMPONENT component
)

install(
    EXPORT foo
    DESTINATION cmake
        COMPONENT component
)
```

The purpose of these rules is to enable foo-extra.cmake to run when a downstream project does "include(foo)", in addition to running the foo.cmake and foo-release.cmake that were generated by the install(EXPORT). In fact "include(foo)" will run every foo-*.cmake file in the same directory as foo.cmake because of code generated in foo.cmake by CMake.

My problem is that install(FILES) seems to always run before the install(EXPORT), and the install(EXPORT) deletes every foo-*.cmake when it decides to generate a new version of foo.cmake and install it. This leads to the following deplorable sequence of events:

```
install foo-extra.cmake
delete foo-extra.cmake
install foo.cmake
install foo-release.cmake
...later on downstream
include(foo)
...CMake freaks out about missing stuff
```

Note CMake doesn't complain about foo-extra itself being missing, it only knows that some definitions the downstream project relies on are missing because foo-extra wasn't there when foo.cmake went looking for files named foo-*.cmake.

Running "make install" a second time works, because the cmake rule to generate a new version of foo.cmake decides nothing needs to be done so the install(EXPORT) rule doesn't delete anything. foo-extra.cmake gets installed as expected and everything is good for the downstream project to run. foo.cmake rarely gets regenerated so this race condition isn't seen very often, but when it does it's a bit of a surprise. Mostly it seems to happen when something changes in CMakeLists.txt (it's unclear what the trigger is).

Answer (score 1):

CMake 3.18 documents such behavior for [install(EXPORT)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/install.html#export) command:

> **Note** The installed `<export-name>.cmake` file may come with additional per-configuration `<export-name>-*.cmake` files to be loaded by globbing. Do not use an export name that is the same as the package name in combination with installing a `<package-name>-config.cmake` file or the latter may be incorrectly matched by the glob and loaded.

That is, one shouldn't create files matching to `<export-name>-*.cmake` at all, otherwise these files will be loaded on `find_package` call (because created `<export-name>.cmake` take those files by globbing).

Actually, you needn't to have EXPORT name the same as the package name. Instead, use (for example) `fooTargets` name for EXPORT, and create `foo-config.cmake` script **manually**. That manually created script could include auto-generated `fooTargets-config.cmake` and e.g. include your own `foo-extra.cmake` with additional macros/variables.

Note, that [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages) also suggests to **manually** create `<package>-config.cmake` script. It also suggests to use `generate_export_header` for configure that script.

Comment: I want foo-extra.cmake to be loaded. It turns out I have two problems. One, install() directives order matters. I need to swap the order of the above install() commands. Second, they were in different CMakeLists.txt. That made my install ordering undefined.